# How to avoid mixed naming conventions on Laravel Eloquent Model properties and methods

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I´ve a question to **naming conventions in Laravel/Eloquent** Models.
When using combined names for table attributes like "Product categories" or "Car Owner" the naming conventions is to use snake case, so it would be "product_categories" or "car_owner".

On the other hand PHP and Laravel use camel case for method names with leads to a mixup of both conventions when using models with relationsships. Cause there I have to use methods for linking related models (belongsTo etc.)

**Here is an example:**

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{

    // Example for a direct property in that product model:
    // "capacity_qty" (Double)        

    // Get the capacity unit object from related model
    public function capacityUnit(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(CapacityUnit::class);
    }
}
```

As you can see the product model has two properties which now have to be accesed following different naming conventions:

- $product->**capacity_qty** for the direct model property (snake case)
- $product->**capacityUnit** to fetch the CapacityUnit object related to the product (camel case)

I followed the official Laravel Documentation but there was no example for combined method/property names.

Do you have a hint for me how to always use camel case for method and properties in that case without creating helper methods for each property and without breaking the naming convention on DB side?

Thanks & best wishes,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is case insensitive so

```sql
select capacityQty from CapacityUnit

//is equivalent to

select capacityqty from capacityunit
```

Hence it has been a convention to use lowercase for table and column names.

In Laravel model properties represent column names for the table wherein all records for the Model's entity will be stored

Hence following the conventions of SQL, Laravel also uses lower case for table names and Model's property names

However for class names, it follows the convention of using PascalCase - widely accepted and followed in various Object Oriented programming languages

> I totally understand both conventions and both make sense. Howeve it leads to an inconsistent way of accessing properties in models with relations.

Unfortunately/fortunately yes - that's due to the fact - that SQL/databases and Object Oriented programming languages are basically different worlds and follow different conventions.

You can follow a **consistent** convention in naming your tables and column names. For eg:

Table name: PascalCase or lowercase plural as per convention

Column name: camelCase

Being consistent is the key thing to remember.

However following the above convention will require some extra work when working with Laravel

- Declare the table property on model class `protected $table = 'CapacityUnit'`
- Specify the column name when defining relationships, if the foreign key is in camelCase and table name

Then you can use camelCase for model property names.

But as is evident - trying to do consistent way of accessing properties using camelCase necessitates significant extra efforts when using Eloquent and seems not worth. Plus there's always a possibility of human error factor especially in team environment.

For most part using relational databases like MySQL, Postgres , SQL Server, there would not be any major issue except may be some side effects in certain edge cases.

However there are some modern databases which follow a convention of either all uppercase or lowercase, where there could be significant side effects.

Comment: I totally understand both conventions and both make sense. Howeve it leads to an inconsistent way of accessing properties in models with relations.

Comment: @MichaelFürst Have added a few more thoughts to the answer

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. However I can´t understand why Laravel maps the column names to snake case. Think it should be quite easy to map snake case to camel case in the property name. As far as I can remeber Symfony does it that way, so methods and properties are always written in camel case in each and every class which makes usage much clearer in my opinion.